# Manually add a DNS "A" record in a text file (no cPanel, ancient server)

Tags: linux, dns, redirection, subdomain

My boss has me working on an ancient server at his place where there is no fancy cPanel to create sub/addon domains.

Basically what we have is a plain-text file that appears to be controlling all the records for the domain.

The actual site is hosted on: 198.164.196.74
The URL is: http://cif-ifc.org/

We need a subdomain, "application.cif-ifc.org", to send the user to a DIFFERENT server (69.195.124.54) using an A-record (we think).

I would know how to do this with cPanel, but NOT with this plain text file that you see below:

**Here is our plain text "DNS control" file, called "db.cif-ifc.org":

```
$TTL 600
@   IN SOA dns.cif-ifc.org. admin.cif-ifc.org. (
                          2012081003    ; Serial
                          600       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          600       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          600       ; Expire after 1 day
                          600 )     ; Minimum TTL of 1 day

@   IN NS   dns.bids.ca.
@   IN NS   dns2.bids.ca.

cif-ifc.org.    IN  A   198.164.196.74
dns     IN  A   198.164.196.150
pubs        in  a   129.41.23.234
staging.pubs    in  cname   pubs
maint       in  cname   maint.literatumonline.com.
backup      in  cname   honoredsoft.com.
*       IN      cname   cif-ifc.org.

cif-ifc.org.    in  mx  10  aspmx.l.google.com.
cif-ifc.org.    in  mx  20  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
cif-ifc.org.    in  mx  20  ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
cif-ifc.org.    in  mx  30  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
cif-ifc.org.    in  mx  30  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
cif-ifc.org.    in  mx  30  ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
cif-ifc.org.    in  mx  30  ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

Would any of you super-user duders mind providing some insight or pointing me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: What's not to know? Just copy the line starting with "pubs" and replace "pubs" with "application" and "198.168.196.150" with "69.195.124.54". I really don't see how you could not have figured this out from the format of the file ?

Answer (score 0):

```
cif-ifc.org.             IN  A   198.164.196.74
application              IN  A    69.195.124.54
dns                      IN  A   198.164.196.150
pubs                     in  a   129.41.23.234
```

As suggested in comments by @Zoredache change this line:

```
                  2012081003    ; Serial
```

to

```
                  2013052901    ; Serial
```

That should work for you. Remember to backup config and to reload bind.

Comment: And update the serial number.  Don't forget the serial.

Comment: Will also need to reload the bind config either via appropriate script or `kill -1`.